# Return object of class containing variables values

Tags: java

I got a class named `Figure` with 3 variables in it. On my task I got this question. I am wondering if I am missunderstanding this, it says "object of class". Am I doing it wrong?

```
Create a method `toString()` which will return an object of class
String object containing the name of the figure together with the values of its area and perimeter, in case they are greater than zero. 

Test the method by creating an object, modifying its fields and printing it to the screen without explicitly calling the toString() method (System.out.println(object)).
```

```java
  public String toString() {
        if(this.perimeter > 0 || this.squareArea > 0)  {
            return this.perimeter + " " + this.squareArea + " " + this.name;
        } else {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It just means return a `String` object.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few things here that we can improve upon. I also don't fully understand your question, so bear with me if there's something you're still confused about.

Firstly, you have "if perimeter is greater than 0 OR area is greater than 0". That means if you have a positive perimeter and a negative area, it'll still print out your perimeter and area. I think what you're lookin for might be this:

```
if((this.perimeter>=0) && (this.squareArea >=0)) {
    return this.perimeter + " " + this.squareArea + " " + this.name;
}
```

Secondly, we can make that print statement a little more clear by returning:

```
return this.name + " perimeter is " + this.perimeter + ". Area is " + this.squareArea + ".";
```

Lastly, if you're just trying to make a toString() function, you've got it! What concerns me what the "object of class" means. My best guess is that you're thinking correctly because the toString() method will be what outputs when you do System.out.println(object). It seems to me this is just a weirdly worded question. I think you're on the right track.

And remember to accurately test your homework question, make an object. Edit its perimeter and/or area. `System.out.println(object)`. Then edit it again and do `System.out.println(object)` again and watch how the message changes!